# Appearance of Karyotypes in educational material

Tags: karyotype

Most actual karyotypes online appear as single chromosomes (unreplicated). I was under the impression that a micrograph of the replicated chromosomes was taken during metaphase of mitosis and thus should show up as duplicated sister chromatids instead of single chromatids post anaphase.  Are the arms of the chromatids just so close to each other that they are hard to distinguish?

Answer (score 0):

Many karyotype images, especially those used for introductory educational purposes, have been edited to show a regular human 2n. For example this image has been edited to depict a regular 2n (46) compliment of human chromosomes.

[image]

While this image is unedited and shows the replicated homologous pairs in metaphase:

[image]

Comment: So the first image you supplied does not show replicated chromosomes consisting of two chromatids for each of the chromsomes in the first pair?

Comment: Correct, the first image shows the normal 2n of 46 chromosomes arranged in 23 homologous pairs. The second image shows the replicated chromosomes at metaphase with the sister chromatid pairs arranged in tetrad with their homologues. If you look closely at the second image you can even see the centromere holding the sisters together.

Comment: This is incorrect; both images have been edited (to form pairs), and both are from cells in metaphase, which therefore have sister chromatids present.  (One is human and one is bird.) Both have chromosome images which clearly show the pinched waist caused by the centromere.  Some show the division between the chromatids, but the contrast in the second makes this easier to see.

Comment: I don't see the difference either

Comment: Can you add your sources to the figures?